# JQuery Confirmation dialog focus causes dropdown on main window to lose focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, confirmation

I have a JQuery dropdown menu set up so that when a particular selection is made a confirmation dialog (also JQuery) is displayed with a comment field and a yes/no button. I want for the user to be able to enter text and click yes or no on this confirmation window while the state of the dropdown menu in the background remains the same.

Unfortunately, as soon as I click anywhere in the Confirmation window, the state of the dropdown menu in the background is lost--It goes back to the default state. Is there some simple option for handling this? Making it modal has no impact.

Below is my confirmation window definition:

```
 $(".change_status").Confirmation({
      header: "#{t.global.conf_header}",
      onload: function(){
        $("#newSync > .date_chooser").each( function(index, element){
          var minDate = new Date().addDays("#{medsync_post_offset}");
          var maxDate = new Date().addDays(100);
          calenderize(element, $(this).next(), null, minDate, maxDate);
        });
      },
      message: function(){
        if ($(this).html()=="#{t.medsync.resume}"){
          $("#activate").show();
          return $("#activate").html();
        }
        if ($(this).html()=="#{t.medsync.hold}"){
          $("#hold").show();
          return $("#hold").html();
        }
        if ($(this).html()=="#{t.medsync.remove}"){
          $("#activate").show();
          return $("#remove").html();
        }
      },

      buttons:
      [
        {text:"#{t.global.button_yes}", label: "Yes_btn", action: function(e)
           {
             //if ($(this).html()=="#{t.medsync.hold}" && $.trim($("input:text.comment:visible").val()).length < 1)
             if($("input.required:visible").size() > 0 && $.trim($("input.required:visible").val()) == "")
             {
               e.stopImmediatePropagation();
               $("input.required:visible").css("border","2px solid red").focus();
             }
             else
             {
               if ($(".required input:text:visible").size()>0 && $.trim($(".required input:text:visible").val()) == "")
               {
                 //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                 $(".required input:text:visible").css("border","2px solid red !important;").focus();
               }
               else
               {
                 $.post($(this).attr("href"), $("form#sync_form").serialize()+"&"+$("form.status:visible").serialize(), function(response)
                 {
                   if (response=="OK") { window.location.reload(true);}
                 });
               }
             }
           }},
        {text:"#{t.global.button_no}", label: 'No_btn', action: function(){return false;}}
      ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a perfect solution and a bit of a hack, you could store the selected index of the dropdown and/or pass it to your dialog, and then set the dropdown to the selected index upon dialog close, and optionally set the focus back to the dropdown.